# What are all of the emblems/patches in COD Ghosts and how do I unlock them?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Does anyone have an exhaustive list of patches and their unlock requirements?

Answer (score -1):

There is an unofficial spreadsheet here with them in:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byux3MwGjNRBUkxZRDZzNnFIWW8

Its a slow loading document though, and I cannot verify 100% the accuracy of the data therein.